# Batch Message Consumption for JMSItemReader-Spring Batch

Tags: java, jms, spring-batch, batch-processing, solace

I'm working on a POC where requirement is to consume messages in a batch from a JMS queue and pass it to processor and writer in chain as per Spring batch Step..Spring Batch provides `JMSItemReader` as a out of box functionality  but looks like it consumes messages one by one until there are no messages left in queue or receiver timeout is reached...As far as Chunk based step is concerned, Items are read into chunks,which are processed and then written within transaction as a chunk into another datastore..Here `JMSItemReader` doesn't read items in a batch..Is there any solution in Spring Batch world to consume messages in a batch from a queue to improve overall performance of an application?

I tried a lot of documentation but didn't find any appropriate solution for this use case..appreciate your help..Thank you

Comment: It's worth noting that the JMS API itself supports "batching" only via transactions. The API only supports sending and consuming messages individually, and transactions can be used to ensure these operations are committed or rolled back atomically. Furthermore, asking whether or not performance can be improved in your situation is like asking, "How long is a piece of string." The answer, of course, is, "It depends," and such questions are off-topic on Stack Overflow because they generate discussion rather than fact-based answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the [BatchMessageListenerContainer](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-infrastructure/src/test/java/org/springframework/batch/container/jms/BatchMessageListenerContainer.java) is what you are looking for. It allows you to read messages in batches.

Note that this is not part of the standard library of readers/writers, but you can use it as is if you want or take inspiration and adapt it as needed.

Comment: thank you..Do you think standard JMSItemReader would be performant enough considering moderate real time work loads on queue.. i.e Dequeuing app which would read message one by one using JMSItemReader,process it using some transformation logic & finally accumulate them when certain batch size/receiver timeout is met,write it in single transaction using ItemWriter(file/db)

Comment: Yes, in this case I think the JmsItemReader is fine.